# Schnorr NIZK over Ed25519

Tags: elliptic-curves, zero-knowledge-proofs, libsodium

I am trying to implement the following Schnorr non-interactive zero-knowledge protocol: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8235#page-7

I'm using the libsodium 1.0.16 and GNU MP libraries.

I just can't seem to get it working. Here are some questions:

```
    In the setup of the scheme, Alice publishes her public key
    A = G x [a], where a is the private key chosen uniformly at random
    from [1, n-1].
    
    The protocol works in three passes:

   1.  Alice chooses a number v uniformly at random from [1, n-1] and
       computes V = G x [v].  She sends V to Bob.

   2.  Bob chooses a challenge c uniformly at random from [0, 2^t-1],
       where t is the bit length of the challenge (say, t = 80).  Bob
       sends c to Alice.

   3.  Alice computes r = v - a * c mod n and sends it to Bob.    

   At the end of the protocol, Bob performs the following checks.  If
   any check fails, the verification is unsuccessful.

   1.  To verify A is a valid point on the curve and A x [h] is not the
       point at infinity;

   2.  To verify V = G x [r] + A x [c].
```

Regarding step (3) on the computation of `r = v - a * c mod n` it means that this step is using regular modular arithmetic?

Regarding step (2) on the verification `V = G x [r] + A x [c]`, can you please explain how that would hold? Is the following equivalent: `V = ed25519_scalarmult(r, ED25519-BASE) + ed25519_scalarmult(c, A)` where `ed25519_scalarmult(scalar, point i.e. publickey)`? And most importantly that `+` is Ed25519 point addition?

Comment: This looks very interactive not NIZK

Comment: It is "non-interactive" because there are only 3 steps or so, instead of at least n interactive steps for a 2^n security level.

Comment: If it's Alice, Bob, Alice and then Bob verifies I call this interactive.

Comment: You can make this non-interactive by using the Fiat-Shamir heuristic. You replace step 2 by `c = Hash(X || A || G)`. This step can be computed by Alice and the whole scheme is now non-interactive.

Comment: To fill in more blanks of things I've learned since, Ed25519 is obviously not a prime order group. You can use Ristretto https://ristretto.group/ to convert Ed25519 points to an encoding suitable to use with protocols requiring prime order groups. From what I can see, Ristretto is implemeted in libsodium, so I should try again. :)

Comment: @stojanman Yes. For reference, that is what Substrate (https://www.parity.io/substrate/) uses for most of its signatures. The exception is the block validation protocol, which still uses Ed25519.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Regarding step (3) on the computation of `r = v - a * c mod n` it
> means that this step is using regular modular arithmetic?

Yes.

> Is the following equivalent: `V = ed25519_scalarmult(r, ED25519-BASE) + ed25519_scalarmult(c, A)` [...]?

Yes, see also [section 1.2 (near the end)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8235#section-1.2) where it says *"`P x [b]`: multiplication of a point P with a scalar b over E(Fp)"*.

> And most importantly that + is Ed25519 point addition?

Yes, that is indeed the case, `+` represents the *group operation* here, which is modular-reduced multiplication for the finite field and point-addition for the EC case. This can be seen when looking at [section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8235#section-2.2).

> `V = G x [r] + A x [c]`, can you please explain how that would hold?

I'll use a slightly more tense notation ($\xleftarrow{\\\$}$ means that the variable on the left is sampled uniformly at random from the set on the right).

1. Pick and publish your public key $A=[a]G$ with $a\xleftarrow{\\\$}\{1,...,n-1\}$
2. Pick $v\xleftarrow{\\\$}\{1,...,n-1\}$, send $V=[v]G$.
3. Pick $c\xleftarrow{\\\$}\{1,..,2^t-1\}$, for some security parameter $t$, send $c$
4. Compute $r=v-a\cdot c\bmod n$ and send $r$.

Now the question is why $V=[r]G+[c]A$ holds in an honest protocol execution. Well $$[c]A+[r]G=[c\cdot a]G+[v-a\cdot c]G=[c\cdot a+v-a\cdot c]G=[v]G=V$$

Comment: I have another question. `n` is I'm assuming the order of the curve? Therefore for 25519 that would be `2^252 + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493`?

Comment: @stojanman yes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I still haven't gotten it to work, but I think the fault is somewhere in the bit order of the libraries.

Comment: P.S. This is how long it took to get it working. Main fault was in libsodium, in that it clamps the scalars according to some awkward rule. I will submit a PR on libsodium that does not do this.